# "bitter cold" current usage

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

*'tis bitter cold. And I am sick at heart.*
**Hamlet, William Shakespeare**

How common is the term "bitter cold"?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j-_90BjgaDc&ab_channel=BAREILIVE

I heard the term used in this song.

Comment: Are you questioning "bitter cold" vs. "bitterly cold" ?  Since "cold" is an adjective here...

Comment: Laura, if you [edit] your post to ask about *current usage* of the phrase, your question will be less likely to get closed. There's a big difference on our site between asking if something "sounds natural" (off-topic: we don't provide proofreading services or help people learn to speak fluent English) and asking about the *usage* of a known word or phrase - for instance, whether it's no longer used, or it's only used in (say) Scotland. For further guidance, please read [ask] and take our **[Tour]**. :-)

Comment: But now your question has changed radically and is superficially far more basic. On ELU, you would be expected to add basic research, such as Google ngrams for 'bitter cold', 'bitterly cold', 'it's bitter cold', 'it's bitterly cold' ... and raw Google search results (numbers of hits). The original question, about whether 'I'm bitter cold', with a sentient experiencer, was of ELU standard if slightly inappropriately phrased.

Answer (score 0):

[These Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wind+was+bitter+cold%2Cweather+was+bitter+cold%2Cit+was+bitter+cold%2Che+was+bitter+cold%2Cwall+was+bitter+cold&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwind%20was%20bitter%20cold%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cweather%20was%20bitter%20cold%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cit%20was%20bitter%20cold%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20was%20bitter%20cold%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cwind%20was%20bitter%20cold%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cweather%20was%20bitter%20cold%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cit%20was%20bitter%20cold%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20was%20bitter%20cold%3B%2Cc0) / and [these](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wind+was+bitterly+cold%2Cweather+was+bitterly+cold%2Cit+was+bitterly+cold%2Che+was+bitterly+cold%2Cwall+was+bitter+cold&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwind%20was%20bitterly%20cold%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cweather%20was%20bitterly%20cold%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cit%20was%20bitterly%20cold%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20was%20bitterly%20cold%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

[image]

would strongly suggest that 'bitter/ly cold' is used principally for the elements and natural environments (including the 'weather *it*'
usage), very rarely for sentient beings.

However, ngrams for 'bitterly cold region' and 'bitterly cold year', which I'm sure are fully idiomatic, show infrequent usage. I think this is probably down to sampling imbalances. 'I'm bitter/ly cold' gives not very many relevant hits in a raw Google search.

And in fact [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/bitter) gives a covert caveat about the usage of this sense:

> **Bitter** [adjective]: '''
> [B2} **Bitter weather** is extremely cold, especially in a way that causes physical pain:
>
> - *a bitter wind*
> - *Wrap up warmly - it's bitter outside.*

The corresponding adverbial (modifier-of-adjective) sense in 'bitterly cold' retains this restriction.

Comment: It's not [that](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+was+quite+cold%2CI+was+freezing+cold%2CI+was+bitter+cold%2CI+was+extremely+cold&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20was%20quite%20cold%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20was%20freezing%20cold%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20was%20bitter%20cold%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20was%20extremely%20cold%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CI%20was%20quite%20cold%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20was%20freezing%20cold%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20was%20bitter%20cold%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20was%20extremely%20cold%3B%2Cc0) rare.

Comment: I left *very cold,* the most common phrase, out of the Ngram because there wasn't enough room in the comment.

Comment: Edwin, it would be useful to know whether there's a regional dimension to its usage. I've seen/heard the expression (old books, or maybe period dramas?) but it sound very odd to Australian ears; is it more BritE than AmE? Perhaps more of a relic, only current in certain parts of the UK?

Comment: @ChappoHasn'tForgottenMonica _Bitterly cold_ seems a perfectly normal expression to me (UK, 60+) - but of the weather, not how a person feels (as Edwin said).

Comment: I'm from Oldham, NW of Kate's Derby.

Comment: @Peter The examples seem of mixed pedigree (but then that's normal). But there does seem to be bimodality: the dubious and the literary (I'm not going to argue with 'Terror overcome Pippin and Merry.... Frodo was hardly less terrified than his companions; he was quaking as if he was bitter cold, but his terror was swallowed up in a sudden temptation to put on the Ring. ') I've found one good example other than in these domains.

Comment: @ChappoHasn'tForgottenMonica You say "it sounds very odd to Australian ears" - perhaps for the very obvious reason that in most populated parts of Australia it never gets bitterly cold!